# Prove ring of dyadic rationals is a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain

This is a question from page 105, [Vinberg - A course in Algebra](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-56):

*Prove that the ring $A$ of rational numbers of the form $ 2^{-n}m,~m \in \mathbb{Z},~n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, is a Euclidean domain.*

Here $\mathbb{Z}_+$ contains 0. I try to find a norm $N \colon A \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ that satisfies Euclidean algorithm. I suppose that $N$ has to satisfy the following conditions:

1. Since each rational number is an equivalent class, the norm $N$ **must not depend on the representative** of the equivalent class.
2. $N$ somehow **measures the "distance"** between elements in A and 0 (as we did for the case Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$) because we need to compare the norms of divisor and remainder.

However, I can't find any reasonable formula for $N$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each nonzero element in the ring is $2^ka$ where $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $a$ an odd integer. Define $N(2^ka)=|a|$,